# Parse a typescript file and add some code

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to generate some code using typescript
This is a program that sits independently of another project (also in typescript)
It should read a file similar to the one below:

```js
import {and, or, xor} from "../lib/operators";

import valueFor from "../lib/valueParser";
import {C1, C2, C3} from  '../lib/constants'
export default {
    'Alpha': {path1: or(C1, C1).and(or(C1,2)},
    'Beta': {path1: and(C2, C3), path2: and(C2, C3)},
     //Comment added by someone, should ideally be retained

}
```

So basically, I want to overwrite the default export each. For example, it should add a Theta if needed. However, if Theta is already defined, it should leave it alone.  I also want to be able to do the same for paths. If trying to add a path2 to alpha, it should leave it alone if defined, otherwise insert the value it thinks is right.

```
    'Alpha': {path1: or(C1, C1).and(or(C1,2), path2: or(C2,C1)},
    'Beta': {path1: and(C2, C3), path2: and(C2, C3)},
     //Comment added by someone, should ideally be retained
    "Theta": {path1: valueFor("New Operator")}

}
```

I thought of doing a JSON parse after extracting. But since it's not a JSON value, I had to add some workarounds.

I also want to leave the comments as is. Module resolution is not an issue. The operator who runs the command can fix it.

In effect, I want to:

- Figure out the default exported object (always a default exported object)
- Parse it similar to a json file
- Check if the object key path i.e Alpha.path1 that I want to exists.
- If it doesn't exist, add a default value
- If it does exist, leave it alone
- Do this in place, leaving comments etc alone

Comment: So you basically want something like a C# source generator?

Comment: effectively, yes. I tried ts compiler from microsoft. It seems overkill and doesn't seem to allow manipulating stuff